# What are the odds the 1 person out of 4 who said "thank you" was the only female?

Tags: probability

This is a silly question, but came about from conversation with a coworker.

My coworker did a favor for 4 different people via email.

3 were male and 1 one female.

Only one of the people replied with a "thank you", and it was the only female.

My coworker pointed out this discrepancy.

I'd like to know how to think about this probabilistically....haha

What are the odds that this was random/coincidence?

I assume a basic assumption required are the odds of any person saying thank you, let's say 0.5 (sub-question: how does this assumption change the answer to the question this make a difference? What if it was 0.25 percent?).

My bad-at-probability-best-guess is 0.5**4 = 6%, but that seems way too low!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the chance that a person replies with "thank you" $p$, and assume that this probability is the same for each person, and that the events are independent. That is, we are assuming that whether one person says thank you or not has no bearing on the decision on whether the other people say thank you or not.

Then, the probability that the one female says "thank you", but none of the males do, is $p(1 - p)^3$. In particular, the female has a $p$ chance of saying "thank you", and the males have a $1 - p$ chance of not saying "thank you". Because we assume independence, the chance of all of these events coinciding is simply the product of the probabilities.

When $p = 0.5$, then $1 - p = 0.5$, so $p(1 - p)^3 = 0.5^4 = 0.0625 \approx 6\%$, as you calculated. When $p = 0.25$, then $p(1 - p)^3 = 0.10546875 \approx 11\%$. While $6\%$ doesn't seem likely, you have to remember that, when $p = 0.5$, all outcomes are equally likely, and so no matter what ends up happening, the probability of that happening was always going to be about $6\%$. This is a simple and unavoidable consequence of the fact that there are many equally likely outcomes.

In real life, the assumptions that each person has the same probability of saying "thank you" is unlikely to be reasonable; several personal factors (e.g. upbringing, personality, the value of the given task to the given person, etc) will mean that different people will likely feel more or less inclined to thank you. The assumption of independence also goes out the window if someone hits "reply all", as everyone else will be more inclined to thank you if they know someone else took the time to do so.

If you're trying to understand, from this one real-life example, the probability of a person giving thanks conditional on their gender, then you can't. You'd need a full study for that.

Comment: "probability of a person giving thanks conditional on their gender, then you can't".  But you must be able to, no?  There must be some number that can be associated with a sample size of 4?  Or do the stats hit some sort of "divide by zero" error somewhere below a certain sample size?